# MySQL query command SELECT in c# returns nothing

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have been working with MySql in C# and I have a serious problem that prevents me from doing anything.

When I execute the query in the application, it returns nothing and when I run the code from the server query, it returns the values that I need.

I have tried multiple ways of inserting the query values using Mysql.AddWithValue and using normal apostrophes. Neither of these two ways work.

Here's the query from the program:

```
 string query = "SELECT `Typ_dne`, `Snidane`, `Svacina01`, `Obed`, `Svacina02`, `Vecere`, `Fyz_nazev`, `Fyz_trvani`, `Fyz_teren`, `Poznamka`, `Jmeno` FROM `denni_zaznamy` WHERE `Datum` = '" + date01 + "'"
```

This returns nothing.

Code of the application v2:

```
 string query = "SELECT `Typ_dne`, `Snidane`, `Svacina01`, `Obed`, `Svacina02`, `Vecere`, `Fyz_nazev`, `Fyz_trvani`, `Fyz_teren`, `Poznamka`, `Jmeno` FROM `denni_zaznamy` WHERE `Datum` = @datum";

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datum", date01);
```

This also returns nothing.

But if I enter this code to the query, it shows this:

A picture of the query result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpdYR.png]

Could anyone please help me with this problem?

Thanks very much, 
UnknownWarrior8910

Comment: You need to execute the query, not just generate the query string.

Comment: You have shown only query string and nothing more. Show us all the C# code you've used to retrieve your data.

Comment: Do not use AddWithValue, especially with dates. Is your datum variable a DateTime variable or is it a string? Is the `Datum` column of type DateTime or is it a string?

Comment: Can you please print your query because i have some confusion with inputed date might be there will in diffrenet formate

Comment: I think of what quality of research into executing queries programmatically  was done to simply create the query and not actually run it and I'm telling myself that all that's happened is the OP hasn't pasted the relevant bits of code because the alternative would be mind boggling.

Comment: @Andy Korneyev  Other part of the code is:           `code MySqlDataReader rdr;
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();  

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datum", date01);
               
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                 

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                   

                }
MessageBox.Show(query);
                conn.Close();`

Comment: Note that I have a messagebox that shows the output. Its like this:  `string body = "Do you want to copy data: " + "Typ dne: " + rdr["Typ_dne"] + ", Snidane: " + rdr["Snidane"] + ", Dopol. svacina: " + rdr["Svacina01"] + ", Obed: " + rdr["Obed"] + ", Odpol. svacina: " + rdr["Svacina02"] + ", Vecere: " + rdr["Vecere"] + ", Nazev Fyz. aktivity: " + rdr["Fyz_nazev"] + ", Trvani Fyz. aktivity: " + rdr["Fyz_trvani"] + ", Teren Fyz. aktivity: " + rdr["Fyz_teren"] + ", Jmeno: " + rdr["Jmeno"] + ", Poznamka: " + rdr["Poznamka"];`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who have contributed in answering my question :) 
I have fixed the problem. The cause was that the date variable was TEXT on the server and it needed to be DATE. 
I also had to change the date format to yyyy-mm-dd. 
Stuff that I changed: 
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tufCW.png) 
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGOSz.png) 
Then I changed the way that the program was retrieving the date format from: 
`dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString()`, which displayed the following: 29.06.2016 

But the change that was: `dateTimePicker1.Text` made it display 2016-06-29